# Using a template to create a class type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a `queue.h` that has the basic code for creating a queue. It is coded as a template as well. I'm inheriting that class to be part of my `binarySearchTree` class because I will using `queue`'s methods in the bst. Here's `binarySearchTree`'s class protoype. I'll explain the problem below.

```
template <class type>
class binarySearchTree: public queue<type>
{
private:
    template<class type>
    struct nodeType
    {
        type info;
        nodeType * lLink;
        nodeType * rLink; //might need to put back <type> after nodeType if this doesn't compile
    };

    nodeType<type> * root;
    int getLevelOfNode(nodeType<type> *node, type data, int level);
    void printLevelOrder(nodeType<type> * rootNode);

public:
    binarySearchTree();
    int height(nodeType<type> *p);
    bool search(const type &searchItem) const;
    void insert(const type &newData);
    void deleteNode(const type &deleteItem);
    void deleteFromTree(nodeType<type> * &p);
    int getLevelOfNode(nodeType<type> * node, type data);
    void printLevelOrder();

    int numDups;
};
```

For the definition of the private method `printLevelOrder(nodeType<type> * rootNode)`, I'm trying to create a queue that will store pointers of nodeType objects. For example, in its definition I want to do something like this:

```
template<class type>
void binarySearchTree<type>::printLevelOrder(nodeType<type> * rootNode)
{
    queue<nodeType*> q;    //not working

    //rest of code here
}
```

But that isn't working and I know it must be something with the way I've set up the templates. I'm not very experienced in using templates, so what can I do to fix this?

If you need me to post up the code for `queue.h` let me know. Its structure is the same as this one.

Comment: _"not working"_ isn't much helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's the thing, I'm not sure why. I was hoping someone more experienced would be able to analyze my code to see where my template structure went wrong.

Comment: shouldn't be queue<nodeType<type> *> q; ?

Comment: @RobertWadowski But <type> will be <int> when I create a bst object in the main.cpp. See the dilemma?

Comment: @RobertWadowski read your comment wrong! That fixed it haha. Thanks. Make it an answer so I can check mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `queue<nodeType<type> *> q;`